# Space text evenly when there is a line break

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph tag such as above, these are being loaded dynamically from a database, is there any way using HTML/CSS that I can fix this ugly effect so that the text is split up evenly ie:

Episode 10 When My

Brothers Wake Up

[image]

Comment: can you add the code to your post

Answer (score 1):

You may try following:

```
<style>
div {
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
}
</style>
```

In CSS4, you can also try following:

```
text-wrap: balance;
```

Comment: Yeah, text-wrap: balance; is definitely what I'm going for. Doesn't seem to have a lot of support but looks like there's a plugin or something: https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/balance-text